# How to plot without first row

Tags: matlab

I want to plot the third column without the first row?

```
0   0   0    0
2   1   4    6
3   1   2    5 
4   1   88  55
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = [0 0 0 0; 2 1 4 6; 3 1 2 5; 4 1 88 55];

a(2:end, 3)
```